# jOOQ - dao - primary key of inserted object

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am using the DAO's as generated by jOOQ:

```
<generate>
    <relations>true</relations>
    <records>true</records>
    <pojos>true</pojos>
    <daos>true</daos>
    <interfaces>true</interfaces>
    <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
    <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
    <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>
    <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
</generate>
```

After inserting a POJO to the database, how do I get the created identifier/primary key? The insertion succeeds, but calling `getIdentifier()` on the POJO still returns `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a missing feature in jOOQ 3.5 and is tracked as two independent feature requests:

- [#2536 - In DaoImpl set the Id of the inserted pojo](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2536)
- [#3021 - Add DAO.insertAndFetch() to return the updated POJO from the database](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3021)

Right now, you cannot fetch generated keys on insert unless you implement your own `insert()` method, or extend the code generator to generate that method for you.

Comment: Thanks. I really hope these features will make it into the mext release! :)

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: Let's see if we can revive that issue... It's a backwards-compatibility thing, if I remember correctly